# Ko is not preserving selected value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Please excuse me if anything is incorrect. Posting my first ever Question!
Hi, its been while since i have started working on konckout in my new project. everything was going good until now as am facing with 2 basic problems

1. I am not able to pre select my dropdown list, with the selected subItem value
2. When i try to change the selected subitem its is not preserved

i tried debugging to check whether ko is updating the underlying observable "selectedOption" property of "Item" object, fortunately it is doing but one's i change the item and come back my selected value is not preserved
it going back to the first item in the list.

i couldn't understand what am missing

could anyone explain me why the selectedOption value is not preserved and why am not able pre select my dropdown list

Thanks in advance.

please find the sample in jsfiddle [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/eh5v2e1c/4/)

```js
function Item(data) {
    //debugger;
    this.name = data.name;
    this.subItems = ko.observableArray(data.subItems);
    this.selectedOption = ko.observable(data.option);
    //someother properties of this object
}

function SubItem(data) {
    //debugger;
    this.name = data.name;
    //someother properties of this object
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(
    [
    new Item({
        name: "Item 1",
        option: "Sub 12",
        subItems: [
            "Sub 11",
            "Sub 12",
            "Sub 13",
            "Sub 14"]
    }),
    new Item({
        name: "Item 2",
        option: "Sub 23",
        subItems: [
            "Sub 21",
            "Sub 22",
            "Sub 23",
            "Sub 24"]
    }),
    new Item({
        name: "Item 3",
        option: "Sub 33",
        subItems: [
            "Sub 31",
            "Sub 32",
            "Sub 33",
            "Sub 34"]
    })

    ]);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.onChange = function(vm, event) {
        debugger;
        console.log(vm);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedItem"></select>
<select data-bind="options: selectedItem() ? selectedItem().subItems : [], 
        value: selectedItem() ? selectedItem().selectedOption : '', event: {change: onChange}"></select>
<span data-bind="text: selectedItem() ? selectedItem().selectedOption : ''"></span>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are downloading Knockout?  At least on your jsFiddle, trying to download knockout.2.0.0.js is generating a 403 error.  Does: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwauxwx8/ do what you want it to?

Comment: No its not working. encountering same problem.

Comment: Try this jsFiddle.  I don't think I saved the last one: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwauxwx8/3/  If it doesn't work, I'm going to need a little more explanation about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its working with knockout.js 2x . but its not working with latest version of knockout.js 3x. i am using latest version in my project i require the same result as in your last fiddle but with latest version of KO. could you explain me why its working in old version and not in latest version ? is it a bug in KO?